# Disable all stylesheets inside an element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to disable all external CSS inside of a specific element using StyleSheet.disabled? Not sure if I'm just missing proper syntax. If it's only possible at document level, is there any way I can implement something like this? Thank you.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('#container [rel="stylesheet"]');

for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el.styleSheet[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Here's a working example with document as default selector: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jzv3wdk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a typo in your code:

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('#container [rel="stylesheet"]');

for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Try this link: https://jsfiddle.net/p0v3rdac/

Comment: @user120242 The issue is not related to the use of the item method on the nodeList but rather the incorrect use of the styleSheets property on the DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `href` attribute with a custom `data-href` attribute (as a placeholder) :

```
let elementStylesheets = [... document.querySelectorAll('#container [rel="stylesheet"]')];

for (elementStylesheet of elementStylesheets) {

  elementStylesheet.dataset.href = elementStylesheet.getAttribute('href');
  elementStylesheet.removeAttribute('href');
}
```